# Parse a tree from text File

Tags: c++, parsing

I have a settings file that I want to sort and create a QTreeWidget from. I need help with the sorting part. I guess I should read the file line by line and filter the result based on some characters found in the line.

In this example, each operator should be a top-level element and its parameters the children.

```
Parameters = [
## operator1 ##
#    ('Parametergroup', 'Group', True ),
#    ('RootCount', 'int', lambda gm, v : gm.set_value( 'operator1', 'RootCount', v ), 0, 2147483647, 300 ),
#    ('RandomSeed', 'int', lambda gm, v : gm.set_value( 'operator1', 'RandomSeed', v ), 1, 2147483647, 1 ),

## operator2 ##
#    ('Amount', 'Group', True ),
]
```

Each operator is enclosed by `## ##`, each parameter has a `#` at the beginning but I can't rely on it because this is editable. Each parameter and its values is surrounded by `( )`, with each element separated by commas, but then there are functions as parameters inside, so is pretty complex.

I need to find a way to sort each line identifying each operator, parameter and parameter values. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want a grammar-based parsing tool like yacc or Boost.Spirit.

Comment: What if I just read line by line and test for the character at the start of the line?
I tried:
QString line;
line = inFile.readLine();

But `line` is empty.

Comment: @Tac use a `QTextStream` object to read lines from your `QFile`

Comment: Thanks. I solved this part. It turns out that you can only read once from a QTextStream because the result is temporary. The first time I was reading the whole file, second time I was reading line by line, this variable was always null and empty.